# Connection between sql workbech on my Laptop and Mysql on Google cloud compute engine (not cloud sql)

Tags: mysql, firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there anyway to open a port 3306 between MySQL database running on compute engine in google cloud (not cloud SQL) and MySQL workbench running on your local machine to connect ?

I was able to connect it by opening port 3306 on all networks (0.0.0.0/0) under firewall rules. However, I want to restrict it to connect to my laptop only, not all networks. I have a dynamic IP address but I won't mind creating firewall rule every time I connect. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I researched alot, I guess there is no way to allow your laptop dhcp address at googlecloud firewall. I was able to fix this hurdle by ceating ssh tunnel

Windows Source:  http://quintagroup.com/services/support/tutorials/mysql-windows

Linux Source:  http://quintagroup.com/services/support/tutorials/mysql-linux

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a GCE firewall rule for `tcp:3306` protocol/port and specify your remote IP address as source IP range under `Source filter` of the rule. This will allow access to your MySQL service running on GCE VM only from your IP address.

Since your IP address is a dynamic one, you can use the following `gcloud` command to update the source IP address on firewall rule, whenever your IP address is changed:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules update --source-ranges=<Your IP Address/32>
```

If the IP address of your laptop is changing once it re-connects to Internet, you may use [`Task Scheduler` of Windows OS](https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection?answertab=votes#tab-top) to run the `gcloud` command automatically after new internet connection established.

Also, check this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/990404/how-do-you-get-your-public-ip-address-through-the-windows-command-line?answertab=votes#tab-top) to find out how you can get your public IP address through a command. This will be useful if your computer is connected to a private network and `ipconfig` command does not display your external IP address.

You can find equivalent commands for Linux OS as well.